# How can I get java's parser to be forgiving with badly formed html?

Tags: java, html, screen-scraping

I'm attempting to do some screen scraping however the html being returned is causing an error as there is no header (i think). Below is the code

```
public class xpath
{
  private Document doc = null;

  public xpath()
  {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://blah.com/blah.php?param1=value1&param2=value2");

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    try
    {
      String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
      doc = parserXML(responseBody);

      visit(doc, 0);
    }
      catch(Exception error)
    {
      error.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void visit(Node node, int level)
  {
    NodeList nl = node.getChildNodes();

    for(int i=0, cnt=nl.getLength(); i<cnt; i++)
    {
      System.out.println("["+nl.item(i)+"]");

      visit(nl.item(i), level+1);
    }
  }

  public Document parserXML(String file) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException
  {
    return DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(file);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     new xpath();
  }
}
```

Its throwing the exception "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:"

Is there a way of getting the parser to be a bit more forgiving?

Thanks

Comment: @user169743: who asked the question... I don't think "screen scraping" means what you think it does.  If you're really screen scraping then you're parsing humanly readable output (for example by taking a screenshot of a webpage and OCRing it). It appears you're simply crawling web pages like most web crawlers/search engine do. Which is much easier than real screen scraping.

Answer (score 2):

The Exception you mention isn't anything to do with XML parsing, by the way. It suggests that the URL you provided couldn't be parsed properly. DocumentBuilder's [parse(String uri)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) method thinks that string you are passing is a URI and is trying to parse it as such, so you get your exception.

---

I don't think you can be lenient with Java's default XML parsers. The SAX parser is for XML and must barf if the data is not well-formed.

You likely want to swap your XML parsing stuff for an HTML parser like [this one](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/). There's a list open source HTML parsers for Java [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers). You might be able to find one that exposes a nicer browser-ish API as a bonus.

Comment: HtmlUnit is also a nice one: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net Another favorite is JTidy: http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

There are parsers that can read invalid html/xml. I've used [HTMLTidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) and it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Just print the responseBody string and see if there is some valid content in it ?